# Java OutOfMemoryError in Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, garbage-collection

When I run my Java applications on a Window Azure's `Ubuntu 12.04 VM`, 
with 4 by 1.6GHZ core and 7G RAM, I get the following out of memory error after a few minutes.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

I have a swap size of 15G byte, and the max heap size is set to 2G.  I am using a Oracle Java 1.6. Increase the max heap size only delays the out of memory error. 
It seems the JVM is not doing garbage collection.

However, when I run the above Java application on my local Windows 8 PC (core i7) , with the same JVM parameters,  it runs fine. The heap size never exceed 1G.

Is there any extra setting on Windows Azure linux VM for running Java apps ?

Answer (score 1):

On Azure VM, I used the following JVM parameters

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

to get a heap dump. The heap dump shows an actor mailbox and Camel messages are taking up all the 2G.
In my Akka application, I have used  Akka Camel Redis to publish processed messages to a Redis channel.
The out of memory error  goes away when I stub out the above Camel Actor. It looks as though Akka Camel Redis Actor
is not performant   on the VM,  which has a slower cpu clock speed than my Xeon CPU.

Shing

Answer (score 0):

The `GC` throws this exception when too much time is spent in garbage collection without collecting anything.  I believe the default settings are 98% of CPU time being spent on `GC` with only 2% of heap being recovered.

This is to prevent applications from running for an extended period of time while making no progress because the heap is too small.

You can turn this off with the command line option `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I have tried your suggestion and I still get the out of memory error.